# combine imported css files

Tags: css

I have a style sheet file which imports three other css files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
```

style.css contains:

```
@import url("../ins/style.css");
@import url("commerce/css/style.css");
@import url("../in/custom.css");
```

I would like to improve the loading time and reduce the number of requests, so I want to combine the three css files into one in the same order as they are imported. but problem arise that all layout is messed up. I am really wondering why this is happening since import css file is the same as inlcuding them. any ideas? thanks for taking time to read.

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but with your `@import` based CSS, are all those files definitely being included?

Comment: Using `import` won't help your load time. You should combine the three stylesheets into one and only reference that from your HTML.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen That's exactly what he is trying to do..

Comment: @import directives should appear before any other CSS instructions. Do you have any comments or styles before importing?

Comment: no,,,it is clean as the above code..

Comment: @ZoltanToth No, `import` directives redirects the browser to the different stylesheets. With his current structure, there will still be 4 HTTP requests. I needs to open all the files, and copy the content into one file.

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen, that is what I am trying to do.. but doing so result in all layout messed out.....

Comment: Oh, I misread your question completely. I think we'll have to see the content of your CSS files in order to help. Did you remember to fix the `url() paths` in the CSS files after merging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If commerce/css/style.css is the CSS file that holds the layout, it could be that that path is not correct for all pages. I would ensure that all paths are relative to root to ensure that they are correct across the site. This includes the original href url for your combination css file.

I'm also not so sure if putting three imports in one css is less time for loading as opposed to linking them in the html. If you want to reduce load time you need to reduce number of loads somehow such as only loading internet explorer css when the browser is internet explorer etc.

Let me know of anymore developments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SSI includes](http://www.isitvivid.com/blog/combining-your-cssjs-files-with-htaccess/), [H5BP ant build script](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script) or even [borschik](https://github.com/veged/borschik) to combine your CSS.